# tabnavigation hidden after login React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using tabnavigator and stacknavigator, and after my connection I cannot be redirected to my home navigation unless I add Home to my stacknavigator, but tabnavigator disappears. I would like to know what I should do to be sent to my home navigation, so that my tabnavigator does not disappear.

```js
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      User()
      console.log("Update")
    }, 500);
},)

   const User = async() => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user')
    if (value === null) {
      console.log('disconnecte')
    }else {
      setUser(true)
      console.log("online")
      navigation.navigate('Home')
    }
  }

    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {user === false ? <Authnavigator/> : <Stacknavigator /> }
     </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

StackNavigator

```js
export default function Stacknavigator() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Authnavigator

```js
export default function Authnavigator() {
    return (
        <AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>
            <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

**Update :**

the login navigation to Home works but then to go to the Details view it does not work

```js
export default function Stacknavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Tabnavigator" component={Tabnavigator} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Tabnavigator

```js
export default function Tabnavigator() {
    return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    activeColor="#f0edf6"
    inactiveColor="#6D6D6D"
    barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#171717' }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options= {{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <FontAwesome name="home" size={20} color={(color)} />
            )
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Recherche" component={Search} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <FontAwesome name="search" size={20} color={(color)} />
            )
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Favorie" component={Favorie} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                <FontAwesome name="star" size={20} color={(color)} />
            )
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
```

Authnavigator

```js
export default function Authnavigator() {
    return (
        <AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>
            <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <AuthStack.Screen name="Tabnavigator" component={Tabnavigator} />
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't see a route named `Home` in your `<Stack.Navigator/>`

Comment: If I add Home in stacknavigator I am redirected to Home but the tabnavigator disappears

Comment: try `navigation.navigate('TabNavigator')` instead of `navigation.navigate('Home')`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: try changing `initialRouteName="Home"`  to `initialRouteName="TabNavigator"`

Comment: @Mcalan please use English

Comment: thank you it works I made a mistake

Comment: it works but now my stacknavigator no longer works to go to details

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `initialRouteName` `Home` in your `Stack.Navigator`. You need to point it to `TabNavigator` so that your code should look like this.

```
export default function Stacknavigator() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="TabNavigator"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works but now my stacknavigator no longer works to go to details

Comment: How you are navigating to `Details`? I don't see it in the question?

Comment: I go to details once in Home but details can be found in my stacknavigator

Comment: Can you update the question with new code snippets that you are referring to?

Comment: I edited my post, thank you for your help